# reading a file in shell scripting

Tags: shell

i want to read a file and print it on the screen by shell scripting , so i have find a simple code to do this :

```
#! /bin/bash 

FILENAME=$1
Lines=$(wc -l < $FILENAME)

count=0

while [ $count -lt $Lines ]
do
    let count++
    LINE= `head -n $count $FILENAME | tail -1 `
    echo "$count $LINE"
done
echo -e "\nTotal $count lines read"
```

, but i'm didn't understand the following line :

```
LINE= `head -n $count $FILENAME | tail -1 `
```

any help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will first run `head` on the file, taking the first `$count` lines of the file. It is then piped (`|`) into tail, which (due to the `-1`) will return only the last line of the output of head (i.e. the `count`th line).

This will then get assigned to the `LINE` variable for processing

It's worth noting that this approach will work, but it is very inefficient.

Comment: okay , that's good , but for  `-n` , is it have an espicial meaning ?

Comment: by default head will return the first 10 lines of input. `-n X` tells head to return the first `X` lines instead. the `-1` parsed to the tail call is actually a short-hand for `-n 1`

Comment: and another question , why this approach is inefficent ?

Comment: the inefficiency is because you are reading the file repeatedly rather than just once (look up the `while read` construct)

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
LINE= `head -n $count $FILENAME | tail -1 `
```

doesn't do what you think it should.  It tries to execute the command produced by the output of

```
head -n $count $FILENAME | tail -1
```

with a variable `LINE` (without a value) passed to it.

Instead say:

```
LINE=$(head -n $count $FILENAME | tail -1)
```

which would essentially give the line number `count` in the file.

---

As an alternate, you could say:

```
LINE=$(sed -n ${count}'p' $FILENAME)
```

to get the line.

---

Your script seems to be emulating

```
cat -n filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Very inefficient as others have pointed out. @devnull's observation `cat -n file` is spot on.

To emulate that in bash, I'd write:

```
declare -i linenum=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf "%8d  %s\n" $((linenum++)) "$line"
done < file
```

Comment: i have seen a lot about environment variable `IFS` , could you tell me what is it ?

Comment: The bash manual defines [IFS](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Variables) as "A list of characters that separate fields; used when the shell splits words as part of expansion." Details at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting

Comment: Example: `line="1:2:3"; IFS=: read a b c <<< "$line"; echo $a; echo $b; echo $c`

Answer (score 0):

the following simple script will help

## readfile.sh

```
file=$1

cat $file | while read line
do
    echo $line
done
```

Reading file into an array,

## readfileAsArray.sh

```
file=$1

let index=1

while IFS=$'\n' read -r -a myArray
do
    file_content_array[$index]="${myArray[0]}"
    echo ${file_content_array[$index]}
    let index=$index+1
done < $file
```